# Including the includes in the custom .h file

Tags: c, header, include

I am trying to make a headers file where I put all the includes (`unistd`, `stdio`, ...) in C. However when compiling with 'make' I get an error.

`libft.h`:

```
#ifndef LIBFT_H
# define LIBFT_H

# include <unistd.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned int    t_size;

void    ft_bzero(void *s, t_size n);

#endif
```

`ft_memalloc.c`:

```
#include "libft.h"


void *ft_memalloc(t_size size)
{
    void *ptr;

    ptr = malloc(size);
    if (ptr == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    ft_bzero(ptr, size);
    return (ptr);
}
```

The error:

```
cc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I includes -c srcs/ft_memalloc.c -o objs/ft_memalloc.o
srcs/ft_memalloc.c: In function ‘ft_memalloc’:
srcs/ft_memalloc.c:19:15: error: implicit declaration of function ‘malloc’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   19 |         ptr = malloc(size);
      |               ^~~~~~
srcs/ft_memalloc.c:14:1: note: include ‘<stdlib.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘malloc’
   13 | # include "libft.h"
  +++ |+#include <stdlib.h>
   14 | 
srcs/ft_memalloc.c:19:15: error: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’ [-Werror=builtin-declaration-mismatch]
   19 |         ptr = malloc(size);
      |               ^~~~~~
srcs/ft_memalloc.c:19:15: note: include ‘<stdlib.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘malloc’
srcs/ft_memalloc.c:20:20: error: ‘NULL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   20 |         if (ptr == NULL)
      |                    ^~~~
srcs/ft_memalloc.c:14:1: note: ‘NULL’ is defined in header ‘<stddef.h>’; did you forget to ‘#include <stddef.h>’?
   13 | # include "libft.h"
  +++ |+#include <stddef.h>
   14 | 
srcs/ft_memalloc.c:20:20: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
   20 |         if (ptr == NULL)
      |                    ^~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [Makefile:25: objs/ft_memalloc.o] Error 1
```

The make file:

```
# Compiler and flags
CC = cc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror

# Directories
SRCS_DIR = srcs
OBJS_DIR = objs
INCS_DIR = includes

# Source files and object files
SRCS = $(wildcard $(SRCS_DIR)/*.c)
OBJS = $(patsubst $(SRCS_DIR)/%.c,$(OBJS_DIR)/%.o,$(SRCS))

# Library and header
LIBFT = libft.a
HEADER = $(INCS_DIR)/libft.h

# Targets
all: $(LIBFT)

$(LIBFT): $(OBJS)
    ar rcs $@ $^

$(OBJS_DIR)/%.o: $(SRCS_DIR)/%.c | $(OBJS_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I $(INCS_DIR) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJS_DIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJS_DIR)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJS_DIR)

fclean: clean
    rm -f $(LIBFT)

re: fclean all

.PHONY: all clean fclean re
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Did you link with `ft_bzero.o`?

Comment: What error do you get? [Edit] and shot the complete compiler log. How do you compile? What is your makefile? What is your compiler? Etc. etc.

Comment: OT, but your `ft_memalloc` is essentially `calloc`.

Comment: Have you got surrogate headers for `<stdlib.h>` etc lurking around in the directory hierarchy?  Since you're using GCC (in disguise as `cc`), you can add the option `-H` to the compilation and see exactly which files it is including (be prepared to be surprised by how many headers it includes).  That may point out the problem to you.